# How to add common logic to all module controller actions?

Tags: admin-controller

I have module with license based.I have to check license is valid or not in my all controllers.

Now Actually i'm placing my logic in each action.

Is there any better way to check logic & redirect to different page if license is not valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For all actions of a single controller class, you can override the `preDispatch` or `postDispatch` methods:

```
class YourController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function preDispatch()
    {
        // put logic before controller actions here
        parent::preDispatch();
    }
    public function postDispatch()
    {
        // put logic after controller actions here
        parent::preDispatch();
    }
}
```

If all controllers of your module inherit from a single abstract controller, you only have to write this once in that abstract controller.

In theory you can also use the `controller_action_predispatch_{$frontname}_{$controller}_{$action}` events, but those are more useful if you want to add custom logic to *other* modules.

Comment: if i use redirect in predispatch method session messages not displaying.

Comment: That's because the action will still be dispatched and the session messages rendered, but invisible to the user because he gets redirected. To prevent further dispatching, `$this->getRequest()->setDispatched(true);` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

[fschmengler](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/80235/4564) was explained nicely.

But my  suggestion to use controller_action_predispatch event if **use event**

If use `controller_action_predispatch_{$frontname}_{$controller}_{$action}` then  **servers times need to write observer  for each action and each controller** in `config.xml`.

`controller_action_predispatch_{$frontname}_{$controller}_{$action}` is **best whenever it use on one Action.**

If we use `controller_action_predispatch` event put   **frontenName as checking** condition as a condition on observer

```
$route=$observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getRequest()->getRouteName();

if(Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRouterByRoute($route)=='YOurModuleFrontName' ):

// Do your code;
endif;
```

then it will be reduce code  in config.xml

Comment: This works, but the `controller_action_predispatch` is dispatched for every page. So observing this is going to introduce a small overhead. It's better to do it via `preDispatch()` method.

Comment: yes.. predispatch is good process. But i am talking about   event...  not on preDispatch() function.May be  this  case,you can agree with me! :)

Comment: In cases where the observer is needed, it's true, that's the way to do it, but here it's about doing something in a custom controller. Not a core one.